# error - the first argument must be callable, i get this error while using function

Tags: python, function, schedule

```
for params in read_parameters_input_file.itertuples():
    timings = params.Time
    timing = timings
    base_price = params.Base_price
    stop_loss_pr = params.Stop_loss
    def run_code(timing, base_price, stop_loss_pr):
        ltp_data = kite_connection()
        b120(timing, ltp_data, base_price, stop_loss_pr)
    
    schedule.every().day.at(timings).do(run_code(timing, base_price, stop_loss_pr))
    
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

In run_code function there I'm calling two functions, that's why in run-code arguments have values, which is using in b120 function.
I have this code and when I'm running my code I get an error - the first argument must be callable.
I don't know what am I doing wrong here.
Please help me.

error -
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback please?

Comment: @SyKer of course, but why did you give my question a negative rating?

Comment: @KrishnaGupta it's impossible to tell who voted your question down, usually people do that when they feel a question is trivial or poorly researched. In your case, it looks like you called a function, where you're just expected to provide a reference to a function.

Comment: Is `job_func` a function? Your error is basically saying you need the first argument in partial to be a function.

Comment: @Adid No job_func is not function, it is built-in method in schedule library

Comment: @Grismar I just want to know how can I call in schedule code a full function name with arguments.

Comment: [Schedule's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) specifies that the first argument passed to `do` should be a function. Is `code` a function? To pass arguments you must pass them using `*args` and `**kwargs`

Comment: I don't give ratings.

Comment: @SyKer sorry. I blamed you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule` needs to create a partial and thus needs a "bare" function. However the module does enable you to pass arguments to the function as per the [documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#pass-arguments-to-a-job). So you should be able to do this;

```
schedule.every().day.at(timings).do(run_code, timing=timing, base_price=base_price, stop_loss_pr=stop_loss_pr))
```

Comment: Thank You for this one write, I also tried the same one.